# How to highlight a cell on mousemove in Devex pivot grid winforms?

Tags: c#-4.0, devexpress, pivot, mouseover

I am using devex pivot grid and want to highlight cell (or change background color) on mouse move.

I tried with capturing mouse move event but couldn't get it working. Here is the code I tried:

```
void PivotGrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = PivotGrid.Cells.GetFocusedCellInfo();
    PivotGridHitInfo hitInfo = PivotGrid.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
    if (hitInfo.HitTest == PivotGridHitTest.Cell)
    {
        if (hitInfo.CellInfo.DataField != null)
        {
            // hitInfo.CellInfo.

        }

    }
}
```

I tried to find this no google but no luck.

Can anyone point me to some sample code for the same or help me to complete my sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`PivotGridControl.CustomDrawCell`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridControl_CustomDrawCelltopic) event. In this event you can use [`PivotGridControl.CalcHitInfo`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridControl_CalcHitInfotopic) method to get which cell is located at the mouse cursor point. In `PivotGridControl.CustomDrawCell` event you can use [`PivotCustomDrawCellEventArgs.Appearance`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotCustomDrawCellEventArgs_Appearancetopic) property to change the cell appearance.
Here is the code:

```
private void pivotGridControl1_CustomDrawCell(object sender, PivotCustomDrawCellEventArgs e)
{
    var info = pivotGridControl1.CalcHitInfo(pivotGridControl1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));

    if (info.CellInfo != null && info.CellInfo.RowIndex == e.RowIndex && info.CellInfo.ColumnIndex == e.ColumnIndex)
    {
        e.Appearance.ForeColor = CommonColors.GetWarningColor(UserLookAndFeel.Default);
        e.Appearance.BackColor = CommonSkins.GetSkin(UserLookAndFeel.Default).Colors.GetColor(CommonColors.Info);
        e.Appearance.Font = new Font(e.Appearance.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
}
```

Also, you need to force redraw of your `PivotGridControl` on every mouse move:

```
private void pivotGridControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pivotGridControl1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Great... thanks.... this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't debugged it, but maybe something like this: you remember your hit point and use custom draw.

```
PivotCellEventArgs ci;

void PivotGrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var cell = PivotGrid.Cells.GetFocusedCellInfo();
        PivotGridHitInfo hitInfo = PivotGrid.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
        if (hitInfo.HitTest == PivotGridHitTest.Cell)
        {
            ci = hitInfo.CellInfo;
        } else {
           ci = hitInfo.CellInfo;
        }
    }


private void PivotGrid_CustomDrawCell(object sender, PivotCustomDrawCellEventArgs e) {
  if (ci == null) return;

  if (ci.ColumnIndex == e.ColumnIndex &&  ci.RowIndex == e.RowIndex) {
    e.GraphicsCache.FillRectangle(new LinearGradientBrush(e.Bounds, Color.LightBlue, 
    Color.Blue, LinearGradientMode.Vertical), e.Bounds);
  } else {
    e.GraphicsCache.FillRectangle(new SoldidBrush(Color.White), e.Bounds);
  }
  e.Handled = true;
}
```